# Rails - Ajax fires more than once when using will_paginate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, will-paginate

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to learn using Ajax with Rails. So far so good, I've made basic CRUD operations using Ajax.

But the problem is, for example, when creating a new `post`, It's created only once. But after clicking on one of the pagination links. It's created twice. If I clicked for the third time and added new `post`, It's added three times.

The same goes with deletion (i.e. confirmation window is presented three times if clicked on three pagination links)

Note, pagination is not using Ajax.

Here's my code:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_all, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]

  def index
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      @post = Post.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to posts_url}
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'posts/new' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

  def get_all
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
  end
end
```

---

**index.html.erb:**

```
<div class="form_wrapper">
<%= render 'posts/form_ajax' %>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="result"><p></p></div>

<div class="posts_wrapper">
<%= render 'posts/post', posts: @posts %>
</div>
  <% content_for :javascripts do %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'index_page' %>
  <% end %>
```

---

**posts/_form_ajax.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "shared/form", f: f %>
    <div>
      <%= f.submit "Add" %>
    </div>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <ul>
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |err| %>
              <li><%= err %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**posts/_post.html.erb**

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:action => 'index', :controller => 'posts' } %>
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
    <div class="post">
      <p>Title: <%= p.title %></p>
      <p>Content: <%= p.content %></p>
      <p>
        <%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path(p) %>
        <%= link_to p, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true do %>
            <button>Delete</button>
        <% end %>
      </p>
    </div>

<hr/>
<% end %>
```

---

**posts/create.js.erb**

```
$(".form_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form_ajax') %>");
$(".posts_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/post', posts: @posts) %>");
```

Comment: Did you try turning off turbo-links?  I noticed sometimes it doesn't jive with some javascript files----------------                 **gem file, application.js file** get rid of `//= require turbolinks` in your application file & comment out the  `gem 'turbolinks'` in your gem file, then rebundle

Comment: @kkomaz Yup! That was because of turbolinks. Thanks a lot. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try turning off turbo-links? I noticed sometimes it doesn't jive with some javascript files **gem file, application.js** file get rid of **//= require turbolinks** in your **application file** & comment out the **gem 'turbolinks'** in your **gem file**, then rebundle